# Is flask-socketio slow or am I missing something?

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

all!

I am developing an application which receives data from a temperature sensor and prints it dynamically in a flask-served webpage at localhost:5000.

To receive the data from the temperature sensor, an udp server is employed. The receive function is implemented inside a thread. To "real-time" print data to the webpage, socketio is employed - it all runs inside "app.py".

The problem which I am facing is the slowness to print data in the webpage. To test my code I developed an udp client (client.py) which connects to my app.py and, via user input, sends data. What I am observing is that the socket receives the data (I am able to print everything I send in client.py and everything I receive in app.py) but something between my socketio emit function and the website feedback makes this update process slow.

Am I missing something? Could you guys help me out discovering why is this process so slow in my code?

All help is much appreciated!! Many thanks!!

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import socket
import threading

HOST = ''
PORT = 3456
udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
orig = (HOST, PORT)
udp.bind(orig)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///measurements.sqlite3'
app.config ['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret!"

async_mode = None
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)

def thread_function():
    last_temp = 0

    while True:
        temperatura, client = udp.recvfrom(5)
        temp = float(temperatura)
        print("Temp: " + str(temp))
        print("Last temp: " + str(last_temp))

        if (temp != last_temp):
            socketio.emit('my_response', {'temp': temp})
            print("I am here!")
            last_temp = temp

    udp.close()


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
receive_thread.start()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Home acts as a dashboard for the page
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

client.py

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 3456            
udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dest = (HOST, PORT)

print('Para sair use CTRL+X\n')

msg = input()

while msg != '\n':
    udp.sendto(bytes(msg, "utf-8"), dest)
    msg = input()

udp.close()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temperature sense</title>
    <style>
    img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    button {
      background-color: #4180a0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: white;
      <!--- padding: 32px 64px; --->
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      <!--- margin: 4px 2px; --->
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 128px;
      height: 64px;
    }
    button.button:hover{
        background-color: #2a2349;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #bebbb2;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    measurementPrint{
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #bebbb2;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Connect to the Socket.IO server.
            // The connection URL has the following format, relative to the current page:
            //     http[s]://<domain>:<port>[/<namespace>]
            var socket = io();

            // Event handler for server sent data.
            // The callback function is invoked whenever the server emits data
            // to the client. The data is then displayed in the "Received"
            // section of the page.

            socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
                $('#log').text(msg.temp);
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <img src="/static/images/mentorphotonics.jpeg" class="center" alt="Mentor Photonics"  width="200" height=auto />

        <p>
            <a href=/ ><button class=button >Realtime</button></a>
                <measurementPrint>
                    <b>Temperature: <span id="log"></span></b>
                </measurementPrint>
        </p>
        <p><a href=export ><button class=button >Export</button></a></p>
        <p><a href=about ><button class=button >About</button></a></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

guys

I re-studied the example from Miguel Grinberg's tutorial at https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO and I adjusted the code.
The main issues were:

1. I was not using the "thread = socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)" structed, as he used with the @socketio.event
2. UDP's recvfrom is blocking. To solve this issue I set a timeout "udp.settimeout(0.1)" so it becomes non-blocking. However, now you should use the try;exception pair when the timeout occurs.

Regards, Fávero